# hadoop fs -ls “no such file or directory”

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, uri

If i write the command :

```
[hdfs@nnode ~]$ hadoop fs -ls
```

i get the message :

> ls: `.': No such file or directory

I know that **hadoop fs -ls** by default looks for the folder **/home/hdfs** and so i created it using

> hadoop fs -mkdir /home

and then

> hadoop fs -mkdir /home/hdfs

however i still get the message:

> ls: `.': No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

It's actually `/user/hdfs`, not `/home`

Try

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hdfs
```